# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.web_app'; '__main__' is not a package while importing package from sub folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gevent

I'm getting above error while running my app. I want to import app from web_app/**init**.py into run.py file to run on gevent. My project structure is like:

```
myapp
 |---config.ini
 |---run.py
 |---web_app
        |----__init__.py


run.py

from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import configparser

from .web_app import app
# from web_app.__init__ import app

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('C:/workspace/Python/myapp/config.ini')
PORT = config.get('SERVER', 'PORT')
PORT = int(PORT)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Serving on port ', PORT)
    WSGIServer(('localhost', PORT), app).serve_forever()
```

__init.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['APPLICATION_ROOT'] = '/myapp'
logger = log_configuration.get_logger(__name__)

def simple(env, resp):
   resp(b'200 OK', [(b'Content-Type', b'application/json')])
   return [b'Hello Verimed User']

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
   return jsonify({'tasks': "task"})
```

If I keep run.py beside **init** then it's working fine. But I want to keep run.py outside web_app folder.
How to rosolve this. I tried all the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved above problem after added following code into the **run.py**.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../web_app')
sys.path.insert(0,'./web_app')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the "." in front of "web_app"?

```
from web_app import app
```

You can find some more info in the following link: [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/)